# Finding a base for a series to sum to a constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, roots

I'd like to find the value of $r$ that solves the following equation:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N r^{\frac{-1}{n}} = C \,,$$

where $N$ and $C$ are positive constants.

An approximate method would also work fine for my purpose. I tried the following bound---which is pretty tight---but was not able to get it to any simplified form.

$$
\int_0^N r^\frac{-1}{x} \,\, \mathrm{d}x \le 
\sum_{n=1}^N r^{\frac{-1}{n}} \le 
\int_1^{N+1} r^\frac{-1}{x} \,\, \mathrm{d}x
$$

P.S.---I was not able to find a better title for this question. If you know one, please feel free to replace.